# How to access the Recruiter Lite LinkedIn Account from salesforce?

Tags: integration, linkedin

What I have done:

> I have followed this doc and I am able to access my LinkedIn account
>   https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/oauth2

What I am trying to achieve:

> I want to access my recruiter lite Account. Below screenshots will show how do I go to my recruiter lite Account[image: Go to Recruiter Link]

And on clicking Go To Recruiter, I get this page.

[image: My LinkedIn Recruiter Account]

My task is to access the Projects on this page and fetch data from Projects Tab and display the same in salesforce. Since I am not able to hit the end point of this recruiter page, I am not able to access anything.